# Rainbow Role Color Cog discord.py [QUESTION DROPPED]

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Ok So I found a rainbow role bot which basically just makes a role color into a changing rgb rainbow like effect, and am trying to rework it as a Cog for my own bot.

It's an idea I really like and would like to use it to make my bot's role color rainbow-like...

This is the link for the bot I'm attempting to re purpose into a cog for my own:
https://github.com/az4521/RainbowBot/blob/master/main.py

And here is what i have managed so far:

`rainbow.py`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils
import asyncio
from time import sleep
import os
from colorsys import hls_to_rgb
import json


dothething = {}
default_role = "Ranma Saotomi"


class rainbow(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.Cog.listener(name="on_message")
    async def _on_message_rainbow(self, message):
        global dothething
        if not message.author.bot:
            for channel in self.client.guild.channels:
                if channel.id in "./data/guilds.json":
                    if message.content.startswith("-stop"):
                        await channel.send("stopped")
                        try:
                            dothething[str(message.guild.id)] = 0
                        except:
                            print("err")
                    if message.content.startswith("-start"):
                        await message.send("started")
                        hue = 0
                        if message.content.strip().startswith("-start "):
                            role = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == message.content[6:].strip(),
                                                      message.guild.roles)
                        else:
                            role = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == default_role, message.guild.roles)
                        try:
                            dothething[str(message.guild.id)]
                        except:
                            dothething[str(message.guild.id)] = 0
                        if role and not dothething[str(message.guild.id)]:
                            dothething[str(message.guild.id)] = 1
                            while dothething[str(message.guild.id)]:
                                users = [int(str(x.status) == "online") for x in message.guild.members if
                                         role in x.roles]
                                users.append(0)
                                print(str(message.guild.name) + " - " + str(users))
                                if max(users):
                                    for i in range(50):
                                        if not dothething[str(message.guild.id)]:
                                            break
                                        hue = (hue + 7) % 360
                                        rgb = [int(x * 255) for x in hls_to_rgb(hue / 360, 0.5, 1)]
                                        await asyncio.sleep(1 / 5)
                                        clr = discord.Colour(((rgb[0] << 16) + (rgb[1] << 8) + rgb[2]))
                                        try:
                                            await self.client.edit_role(message.server, role, colour=clr)
                                        except:
                                            print("no perms" + str(message.guild.name))
                                            dothething[str(message.guild.id)] = 0
                                else:
                                    await asyncio.sleep(10)

                        
def setup(client):
        client.add_cog(rainbow(client))
```

I'm using a `.json` data storage to store the `guild.ids` and `channel.ids` of each and every guild my bot is currently in and would like it to check to see if the channels exist before actually running.

Now, I've actually never seen anything like this before and am loving the concept.

So, my question is, can anyone see any errors in my code above and if so can you help me fix them?

I'm running off of `discord.py-rewrite` if it helps.

**--EDIT--**

*Ignore this! I just found a post by the official Discord Twitter saying Rainbow Roles are not allowed I'm dropping this one....*